# how to upload multiple files with flask_restful?

Tags: args, flask-restful

I'm trying upload multiple files with flask_restful, but can't get the files name list in the arguments except the first file name,  how can i get the files list with args?

here is my code,

```
from models import Server
import werkzeug
from  werkzeug import secure_filename
from settings import upload_folder,allowed_extensions,currentWorkingPath,os,sys,reqparse,Resource
from settings import fields,marshal_with,abort
from settings import redirect, url_for


'''
#######################################################Uploads API
'''
uploads_fields = {
    'uri': fields.Url('uploads', absolute=True)
}


parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=werkzeug.FileStorage, location='files',required=True)

class Uploads(Resource):
    @marshal_with(uploads_fields)
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()

        print 'file',args
        ......
```

what i got is:

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 115-504-357
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
file {'file': <FileStorage: u'simple_api-master.zip' ('application/octet-stream'
)>}
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 10:40:38] "POST /uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

in fact I selected two files  simple_api-master.zip,simple_api-master-old.rar and passed value throught post method, so the print function should output u'simple_api-master.zip',u'simple_api-master-old.rar', but now it only output the first file name, what should I do to get the files list?

Answer (score 10):

Basically, just add

> action='append'

Your code should be now: `parser.add_argument('file', type=werkzeug.FileStorage, location='files',required=True, action='append')`