# How do I POST multiple files using Flask-RESTPlus?

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, flask-restplus

I want to be able to POST an array of files. I got it working with a single file, but it doesn't work when adding `action="append"` to the parser. When adding `action`, the swagger UI allows me to upload multiple files, but when printing the `files` variable it is `None` even though I have selected multiple files. How can I POST an array of files using Flask-RESTPlus?

```py
    from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource, reqparse
    from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

    file_upload = Namespace(name="files")
    upload_parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
    upload_parser.add_argument(
        name="files",
        type=FileStorage,
        location="files",
        action="append" # If this is removed it works with 1 file
    )

    @files_upload.route("/")
    class Files(Resource):
        @files_upload.expect(upload_parser)
        def post(self):
            args = upload_parser.parser_args()
            files = args["files"]
            do_something(files)
            return ""
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with [`request.files.getlist`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.files)

```
class UploadImg(Resource):

   def store_images(self,image,filename):
       S3_KEY = '************'
       S3_SECRET = '****************'
       S3_BUCKET = '****'
       file='pictures/'+filename
       content_type = request.mimetype
       s3 = boto3.client('s3', 
       config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
                      region_name='ap-south-1',
                      aws_access_key_id=S3_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET)
       s3.put_object(Body=image,    Bucket=S3_BUCKET,     Key=file,       
                  ContentType=content_type)

    def post(self):
       files= request.files.getlist('image')
       for img in files:
           print(type(img))
           print(img.filename)
           self.store_images(img,img.filename)
        return '',201
```

Comment: With this answer, the API will accept files and process them fine, but if you were looking, like me, to find a solution that also helps flask_restplus to understand that it must document the API method in swagger with a file upload input, you may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43214695/5433896.

Answer (score 3):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
import werkzeug
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_restplus import reqparse
import os



file_upload = reqparse.RequestParser()
file_upload.add_argument('doc1',
                         type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, 
                         location='files', 
                         required=True, 
                         help='Document 1')
file_upload.add_argument('doc2',
                         type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, 
                         location='files', 
                         required=True, 
                         help='Document 1')
file_upload.add_argument('doc3',
                         type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, 
                         location='files', 
                         required=True, 
                         help='Document 1')
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app = app)

app.config['Upload_folder'] = './static/'

@api.route('/upload/')
class my_file_upload(Resource):
    @api.expect(file_upload)
    def post(self):
        args = file_upload.parse_args()
        args['doc1'].save(os.path.join(app.config['Upload_folder'],secure_filename(args['doc1'].filename)))
        args['doc2'].save(os.path.join(app.config['Upload_folder'],secure_filename(args['doc1'].filename)))
        args['doc3'].save(os.path.join(app.config['Upload_folder'],secure_filename(args['doc1'].filename)))
        a = [args['doc1'],args['doc2'],args['doc3']]
        print(type(a))
        return {'status': 'Done'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. Using this method, I would have to upload exactly 3 files each time. I want to upload any amount of files